# On mouseover and mouseleave repeating function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function im trying to write that shows a tooltip on hover and fades it out on mouseleave:

```
$('.tt').mouseover(function(e) { 
    var tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');              
    //Set the X and Y axis of the tooltip
    $('.tooltip').css('top', 0 );
    $('.tooltip').css('right', -200);
    tip.fadeIn('500');
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    var tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
    tip.fadeOut('500'); 
});
```

If the user gets erratic with the mouse and hovers multiple times the tooltip flashes, essentially. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: 10 answers in 1 minute... We're a bunch of vultures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`.

```
tip.stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
tip.stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
```

You can find out more about `.stop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: I'm not OP, but I like yours best.  Thank you for both posting the link to the API and providing the optional parameters.

Comment: **This is not the way to go for it**, there's other things you should know about. The effect on faster mousemovements is all but smooth http://jsbin.com/araqiv/3/edit

Comment: I halfway agree with @roXon.  This does do as the OP was requesting.  It prevents the very prevalent animation stacking by jQuery animations (Which boggles the mind how people get it wrong so often), but it does have some choppiness.  This can be what the developer is after, however.  It feels more responsive to mouse actions than the arguably correct way roXon pointed out.  I think both methods are valid but I think I favor the technically correct way roXon pointed out.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks for your understanding, I was just a bit perplexed seeing being downvoted, but nevertheless, it's the fact that new SO users/visitors, looking for a similar problem will always give precedence to `checkmarked` answers.

Answer (score 3):

Add stop() - http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$('.tt').mouseover(function(e) { 

    var tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');

    //Set the X and Y axis of the tooltip
    $('.tooltip').css('top', 0 );
    $('.tooltip').css('right', -200);
    tip.stop().fadeIn(500);

}).mouseout(function(e) {

    var tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
    tip.stop().fadeOut(500);

});
```

Comment: .stop() in your case will do partially the job. There's other things on how to achieve the best results. Here is the demo for the answer you kindly provided: http://jsbin.com/araqiv/2/edit **And it's not something I would suggest doing**

Comment: Why not? How would you improve?

Comment: Improve? you cannot use `fadeIn('500')` but instead `fadeIn(500)` than there's things for `mouseover` and `mouseout` are not suited best, but you should know that. Here's my improvement, but than it actually mirrors exactly my answer: http://jsbin.com/araqiv/4/edit. So your example not only will not work smooth, but it's also wrong. (and has 2 upvotes...)

Comment: I just copied the OP's code and added the stop(), I didn't correct his code. So my answer is correct, I just failed to fix his syntax. I have edited my answer to fix the syntax issue. If you're worried about the 2 upvotes then you should downvote as you see appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tip.stop().fadeIn()` and `tip.stop().fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1):

This might work, try using .stop()

```
 tip.stop().fadeOut('500');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

It is designed to prevent some of these jitters.

Also of interest is Ben Alman's article on [Throttling and Debouncing](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/araqiv/1/edit)**</kbd>

Sure, using the `.stop()` method and `mouseenter mouseleave`

```
$('.tt').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ) { 

    var elOpacity = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 1 : 0 ;
    var $tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');

    $('.tooltip').css({top: 0, right: -200 });
    $tip.stop().fadeTo(500, elOpacity);

});
```

The `.on()` method in the example above allows you to create a 'list' of *events* we're interested in,
than inside a Conditional operator (*Ternary* `(?:)` ) we listen for the `e` (*event*) changes and assing a value for the element opacity passing it to `.fadeTo()` animation method.
`.stop()` will end a previous animation without creating animation buildups.

**Read more:**
http://api.jquery.com/stop/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/
**Additionally explore:**
http://api.jquery.com/hover/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Added a demo just for the amazing @downvoter who does not care explaining his action.

Comment: lol haters gonna hate.  Sorry your answer got downvoted, bro.  Thanks for the helpfully addition.  Hopefully it will get enough upvotes to be more visible to future vistors.

Answer (score 0):

try the actual enter/leave - might not work if the tip is place where .tt loses focus when tip is displayed.

Add a stop, simplify the css to an object.

```
$('.tt').mousenter(function(e) { 
    var tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
    //Set the X and Y axis of the tooltip
    tip.css({'top':0,'right': -200});
    tip.stop().fadeIn('500');
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
   $(this).find('.tooltip').stop().fadeOut('500');
});
```